# Symfony - how to lowercase a form field?

Tags: symfony

I'm a beginner to using Symfony 3.4 and I would like to change a form field to lower case but I don't know how or where :(
In my buildForm with maybe a constraint or in my Controller but I can't target the form field ?

I tried in Twig:

```
<div>{{  form_widget(form.name)|lower  }}</div>
```

I tried in Controller:

```
$form->get('name')->setData(strtolower($form->get('name')));
```

I tried in buildForm:

```
$builder->add('name', TextType::class, ['attr' => array( 'class' => 'text-lowercase' ))
```

If you need to see my Controller :

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    /** @var $formFactory FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
    /** @var $userManager UserManagerInterface */
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    /** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

    $user = new User();
    $user->setEnabled(true);

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    $form = $formFactory->createForm();

    $user->setUsername("null");
    $user->setPassword("null");
    $user->setPlainPassword("null");

    $form->setData($user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $user->setPassword(strtolower($form["name"]->getData(). $form["firstname"]->getData()));
            $user->setPlainPassword(strtolower($form["name"]->getData(). $form["firstname"]->getData()));
            $user->setUsername(strtolower($form["name"]->getData().
                                              $form["firstname"]->getData()));

            if($form["roles"]->getData() == 'ROLE_ADMIN')
            {
                $user->addRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
            }
            else
            {
                $user->addRole('ROLE_USER');
            }

            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);
            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            /*****************************************************
             * Add new functionality (e.g. log the registration) *
             *****************************************************/
            $this->container->get('logger')->info(
                sprintf("New user registration: %s", $user)
            );

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_register');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

             $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            return $response;
        }

        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

        if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            return $response;
        }
    }

    return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/register.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Thank you for any help !

Comment: Please post some code with what you already tried so far.

Comment: What do you want to `lowercase()` the name of the field or the value inside it? Are you using the form with an entity or with an array? Can you maybe post the full controller action?

Comment: I want to lowercase the value of the field and I using the form with an entity User because I save an user in database with registerController of FosUser. I update with my registerController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap following code should be work:

```
$builder->add('name', TextType::class, ['attr' => array( 'class' => 'text-lowercase' ))
```

Comment: It only works in the view but not in Controller and the database

Comment: But, when you submit such data . it will get with lowercase which you inserted.

Comment: You can do it in your entity.  `public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        
        $this->name = strtolower($name);

        return $this;
    } `

Comment: Of course ! with 'strtolower($name)' in setName() it works ! **Thx** !!